# How can I use the R function to find max value of particular attribute based on some condition

Tags: r

Like I have a dataset
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esAIk.png)

So how can i find the max score of 1st innings

Comment: `max(df[df$innings=="1",]$score)`. Assuming  `df` is your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df <- data.frame(innings=c(1,1,2,2,1), score = c(170,189,230,190,210))

inningsScoreSplit <- split(df$score,df$innings)

maxScores <- data.frame(
  inning = names(inningsScoreSplit),
  maxScore = sapply(inningsScoreSplit,max)
)
```

to get

```
> maxScores
  inning maxScore
1      1      210
2      2      230
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good chance to learn tidyverse.
Basically you can do this with one line of code:

```
# This make your dataset
df <- data.frame(innings=c(1,1,2,2,1), score = c(170,189,230,190,210)) 

# This loads up the library tidyverse. 
# If this gives you an error you might need to install tidyverse by using "install.packages("tidyverse")"
library(tidyverse) 

# This calculates the max. There are 2 commands here: filter and summarise.
Result <- df %>% filter(innings == 1) %>% summarise(max(score))
```